# JSON Media Type for for request with AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, jersey

This is the backend Java Side with Jersey in an embedded Jetty.

```
    @GET
@Path("/jason")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public MyJaxBean getMyBean() {
    MyJaxBean myJB = new MyJaxBean();
    myJB.add("Hello", 1);
    myJB.add("World", 2);
    return myJB;
}
```

checking that with curl brings back this text

{"person":[{"name":"Hello","age":1},{"name":"World","age":2}]}

Using that in an HTML Page

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="doRequest()">REQUEST !</button>
<script>
"use strict";
 function doRequest(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/entry-point/jason";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            var myHTML = iterateObject(myArr);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myHTML
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
function iterateObject(myArr) {
  var out = '';
  myArr.person.forEach(function(p) {
       out+= p.name + ',' +  p.age + '<br>';
  });
  return out;
}
</script>
```

brings back

Hello,1
World,2

However this try with AngularJS does not show anthing from the Jason Call

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://localhost:8080/ressources/angular.js"></script>
<body>
<h2>AngularJS doing a JSON HTTP Request</h2>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in persons">
    {{ p.name + ', ' + p.age }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/entry-point/jason")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.persons = response.records;});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Replacing the http.get with

```
$scope.persons = [{name:"Hello", age:1},{name:"World",age:2}]
```

does work.

Any Idea what is wrong with the Media Type or the AngularJS Example ?
Thanks for any help here

Answer (score 1):

Change `<li ng-repeat="p in names">` to `<li ng-repeat="p in persons">`. You are setting the value in `persons` object but using `names` in the view.

**DEMO** http://plnkr.co/edit/0aNUfTwyBJYjQjCsP1UU?p=preview

Comment: Your link doesn't work with names. But locally it doesn't make any difference if there is persons or names. thanks maybe one of many bugs found

Comment: oh and by the way after changing that it does work with your JASON string...so there must be something with the http.get